# How to Update Active Directory attributes using c#.

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can I update active directory attributes using c#. In my case I have the following case. For every user there is a `WhenCreated` attribute in AD, but what i want is, if the `whenDate` is less than 30 days set the `info` attribute to `NEW` in active directory.

How can I do this via c# step by step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [DirectoryEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx). There are lots of examples online on how to use it.

Once you have a DirectoryEntry object bound to an AD object, you can set an attribute like this:

```
de.Properties["info"].Value = "NEW";
de.CommitChanges();
```

If you need to search for object, you can use [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx). You can see an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180885(v=vs.90).aspx), although there are plenty more online too.

Give it a try. If you run into problems, show us what you have.

Comment: How come I got this error when try to modify property 'System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Because there was an error in my code :) I've updated it. You need to use `.Value` to read or assign the values.